# What is the pathname to my application executable?

Tags: applications, adb, root-access, shell, files

I wish to get the pathname for an application I am creating and have installed via Eclipse and ADB.  My application is installed as I see an icon that I can invoke to launch successfully my application.  I also see a file: `/data/app/com.mydomain.myapp-36.apk` however, if I try to invoke that file from the shell I get an error of `can't execute: permission denied`, even though I am root.  I notice that for sshDroid, I can invoke it from the shell using the path: `/data/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/dropbear/ssh` but I find no corresponding path for my application `/data/data/com.mydomain.myapp/` as that directory only contains the subdirectories: `cache`, `files`, and `lib`.

Is there something I can do when building on installing my application so that my application can be invoked from the shell, or do I just need help locating the pathname for my application?

Comment: How are you attempting to invoke it?  You can't run.apk's directly, you have to launch their main activity.  They are not executables, they're basically zip files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To launch applications, use the ActivityManager (`am` command).
Apks are not directly executable as they are just archives containing runnable code.
If you have packaged natively executable binaries in your app, you need to extract them first, then set permissions according to executable permissions (at least `--x--x--x`) and launch it through an instance of shell.